# dd-wrt disabled DHCP, now no longer connects even wired

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I had a perfectly functional DD-WRT router set up with networked file storage, port forwarding, multiple wireless networks, etc.  The router was connected directly to my modem.

I moved to a new apartment where there is an AT&T U-Verse router in place. I began by plugging U-Verse's yellow out plugs into my DD-WRT's yellow in-plug, and although I was able to access my router's admin panel at 192.168.1.1, I couldn't get an internet connection.

I snooped around the dd-wrt site and found something suggesting I should disable DHCP to get a connection.  I did that, and then researted my DD-WRT.

Unfortunately, now, while my DD-WRT wireless network is still visible, I cannot establish a connection either there or to 192.168.1.1---either wired or wirless.  It starts trying to establish the connection then fails.  Even ping 192.168.1.1 says

`connect: Network is unreachable`

As if I were plugged into nothing at all.  How can I re-establish a connection to my router when plugging my machine into it no longer works?  Is there some telnet option?  (This seems impossible since it won't even establish a connection that nothing is going over.)

Comment: A hard reset can be the quick fix solution

Comment: Have you tried setting a static that matches your scope and connecting?